# Are the Stargate glyphs different between Pegasus and Milky Way galaxies and how does it affect the DHD on puddle jumpers?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis, stargate-universe

Since the glyph shapes are based on constellations, wouldn't the Milky Way constellations be a totally different shape, if even existent at all, in the Pegasus Galaxy? Assuming this is the case, which glyphs are used in the puddle jumper DHDs and how can they work in both galaxies? The buttons on the jumpers look like they are real buttons with labels that don't change (vs. touch screens). This (different glyph shapes) can be extrapolated further on the stargates planted throughout the various distant galaxies on *Stargate: Universe*.

I'm not talking about stellar drift over the millennia which is essentially dealt with using automatic periodic software updates to the DHDs. This has been addressed in the first season of *Stargate SG-1*.

Comment: I put my answer below, but thought would just mention an amendment to your question. The glyphs are actually phonetics. When joined together the form a complete "word" in Ancient. The idea of the glyphs being purely constellations was first floated in the original Movie. Since then ancient knowledge and showed them to be phonetics and not simply pictorials.

Answer (score 5):

The Puddle Jumpers on Atlantis have different DHD buttons to the ones on Milky-way Puddle Jumpers.

Here is a picture of a Milky-way DHD:

[image: milky-way DHD]

Note the colour and constellation symbols.

Here is a Pegasus one:

[image: Pegasus DHD]

As you can see the 2 are different, to take into account the constellations. It's a fairly safe bet that the entire console section is replacable on Ancient ships, or can be re-calibrated somehow for the local network with the right experience and tools.

Comment: Can I ask, Is it still called a DHD in a puddle jumper?  the DHD on a Milkyway is very different. To that shown here on either.  Although the symbols in the puddle jumper are the same. But is it a DHD?

Comment: @DubMan As far as I know, the DHD's seen in most Pegasus locations are much similar to the ones we generally see on planets in the Milky Way, apart from colour scheme, and the Atlantis DHD, which uses a similar layout to the Puddle Jumper. As to the name, we know they were referred to in ancient as "**Clavis**", and by Tauri as either DHD or Dialing Computer. Since I can't find any other mention of a different canon name used in context of a Puddle Jumper I'd personally go with Dialing Computer, but only because it seems to be more accurate then DHD.

Comment: @sesquoiad Exactly. Both terms where coin by the scientists dumming things down for people like Jack. So the Dial Home Device and Dialing Computer where only termed after the Stargate's functionality was first explained. Same as the "Puddle Jumper" was coined by a low tech colonel. At no point in SG1 was the device ever "translated" in the same way as the Startgate its self was and referred to in local dialects as the Japa Eye.

Comment: @DubMan And never as "japa eye", either... It's "chappa'ai". :)

Comment: Thank you @T.J.L.  Noted.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a sound. The glyphs themselves are phonetic symbols, so each symbol has a sound, and when an address is put together it spells a word, or planet designation like "Earth" in the ancient language. Refers back to when Jack O'Neill had the ancient knowledge downloaded and he gave Jackson the name or "sounds" of the address to find the "lost outpost" in the build up to the battle with Anubis over Antarctica.